# Creating and overriding a shape to fit into JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

In this program a polygon is created to show up into a `JPanel` tab.

In-order to make it show I had to over-ride the shape and create a setter method for it. Unfortunately it is not showing and the program is not running either.

The error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding
>   a window to a container
>     at SelectShape component1 = new SelectShape(x, y, vert); in method
>   Page1.

The only way it would work is by making a frame and removing the JTab and assigning the shape onto the frame but that is not what I want to make. I want to make a program that can distribute shapes to * different tabs* using one graphics method.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;


/* This program create a graphics component that draws a polygon 
 */
public class SelectShape extends JFrame 
{
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JPanel panel1; 

    // //////////////////////////

    static int[] x = { 20, 40, 50, 65, 80, 95 }; // Co-ords for a polygon
    static int[] y = { 60, 105, 105, 110, 95, 95 };
    static int vert = 6;

    public SelectShape() throws IOException // Builds GUI
    {
        setTitle("Program");
        setSize(900, 600);
        setBackground(Color.gray);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);

        // Create the tab pages
        createPage1();

        // Create a tabbed pane
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Shape Panel", panel1);
    }

    public void createPage1() throws IOException // Creates JPanel
    {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(null);

        SelectShape component1 = new SelectShape(x, y, vert); //error
        SelectShape component2 = new SelectShape(x, y, vert); //over-rides shape

        component1.setBounds(290, 70, 120, 40);
        component2.setBounds(290, 70, 120, 40);

        panel1.add(component1); // is not displayed!
        panel1.add(component2); // component2 overwrites component1!!!
        panel1.setVisible(true);

    }

    // overrides javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Recover Graphics2D
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Construct a polygon then draw it
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon(x, y, vert); 
        g2.draw(polygon);
        g2.fill(polygon);
    }

    public SelectShape(int[] x, int y[], int vert) { // setter method
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vert = vert;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SelectShape mainFrame = new SelectShape(); //Frame
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: `JFrame` does not extend `JComponent` and does not have a `paintComponent` method. 1) Extend a `Jpanel` and set it as the content pane of the `Jframe`. 2) Override `paintComponent` in that `JPanel` 3) Use the `@Override` annotation to prevent situations like this, where you believe your overrode something but actually did not.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Can you add this as an answer?

Comment: `SelectShape` class extends `JFrame`, in that sense, you trying to add a `JFrame` to a `JPanel`, and not the other way around, which is what causing the exception.

Comment: How would I "extend a Jpanel and set it as the content pane of the Jframe"?

Comment: Add @GuillaumePolet (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: @Reimeus I did not put it as an answer because there are other quirks to work around (like the original issue "adding a window to a container"). Let me find some time to put together some kind of actual answer :-)

Comment: I am currently working on it and have no luck yet. I dont want to completely change the code as that will sequester the point of the program...Il appreciate it if anyone can have some time to help me with this. Il try to find a solution myself too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing many concepts together in your code which eventually leads to ununderstandable code.

- `JFrame` does not extends `JComponent` and does not have a `paintComponent` method. Consider using the `@Override` annotation on methods that override another. This will allow you to easily mistakes like this.
- No need to extend `JFrame` anyway and never override the `paint()` method of a Top-level container (`JDialog`, `JFrame`, ...)
- Always invoke the super method of `paintXXX` methods
- `public SelectShape(int[] x, int y[], int vert) { // setter method` is not a setter method. It is a constructor that takes 3 arguments and assign them. In all cases, this does absolutely nothing in your case because you made those variables `static`. Avoid the use of `static` unless if you describe constants, in which case it should be also followed by the `final` keyword.
- Start the UI, and perform all modifications to the UI, on the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT). This can easily be done by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.
- The error you are seeing: *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container* is thrown because you are trying to add a `JFrame` to a `JComponent` which is forbidden. `JFrame` cannot be added to anything. If you want to do that, you need to use `JDesktopPane` and add `JInternalFrame` (but that is another story).

I am not too sure as to what you are trying to achieve, but here is a working code derived from yours which works much better:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/* This program create a graphics component that draws a polygon 
 */
public class SelectShape extends JPanel {

    // Constants
    private static final int[] x = { 20, 40, 50, 65, 80, 95 }; // Co-ords for a polygon
    private static final int[] y = { 60, 105, 105, 110, 95, 95 };

    private static final Polygon POLYGON = new Polygon(x, y, Math.min(x.length, y.length));
    private static final Ellipse2D CIRCLE = new Ellipse2D.Double(100, 40, 45, 45);

    // Class variables
    private final Shape shape;
    private Dimension preferredSize;

    public SelectShape(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
        Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
        this.preferredSize = new Dimension(bounds.x + bounds.width, bounds.y + bounds.height);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return preferredSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.draw(shape);
        g2.fill(shape);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Program");
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                SelectShape polygon = new SelectShape(POLYGON);
                SelectShape circle = new SelectShape(CIRCLE);
                // Create a tabbed pane
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                tabbedPane.addTab("Polygon", polygon);
                tabbedPane.addTab("Circle", circle);
                mainFrame.add(tabbedPane);
                mainFrame.pack();
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: So I assume I have to use an explicit Frame as well as extend it to JPanel opposed to JFrame. Alright. Thankyou! And thanks for explaining my mistake(s) to me also.